# BASH - how to construct a path in an .sh script using external property?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a property `s3Path=s3a://myBucket` in a file `s3-apps.properties`

Currently the path to a `S3` is hardcoded in my bash script:

```
thePath="s3a://myBucket/myApp"
```

I want to get the property from the file instead and concatenate it with `/myApp`

So I'm getting path to the file like this:

```
file="/apps/properties/various/s3-apps.properties"
```

But how do I get the property and concatenate it to construct a path?

I guess that it should be something like this but it did not work for me:

```
thePath="s3a://{$file.s3Path}/myApp"
```

Non of the answers from the `"Duplicate"` helped me in understanding an solving my question. But the `@cody` answer below was correct and helped.

Comment: `bash` doesn't recognize property files. You would need some way of parsing it manually.

Comment: @anubhava records similar to this: `s3Path=s3a://myBucket` `s3Bucket=the-bucket`

Comment: You can do: `source "$file"; export thePath="$thePath;$s3Path"`

Comment: @anubhava, why the `export`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using GNU grep, the following would work:

```
$ s3path=$(grep -Po '(?<=s3Path=).+$' "$file")
$ echo $s3path
s3a://myBucket
```

Comment: is it a correct way to then construct the path like this? `thePath=$s3path/myApp` or do I need quotes here?

Comment: @samba, quotes aren't needed on the right-hand of an assignment when none of the characters in the literal code (not the expansion results) would be otherwise misinterpreted as syntax. In a non-assignment context, you'd need them.

Comment: ...on the other hand, `echo $s3path` isn't great practice -- there *should* be quotes there, as described in [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).